# Please help me with this prolog excercise

Tags: io, prolog

Here is my homework:

> Let f be a file of terms. Define a procedure 
>     `findterm(Term)` 
>   that displays on the terminal the first term in f that matches the Term.
>
> Let f be a file of terms. Write a procedure 
>     `findallterm(Term)` 
>   that displays on the terminal all the terms in f that matches the Term. Make sure that Term is not instantiated in the process (which could prevent its match with terms that occur later in the file).

I tried using cut to solve the first one

```
 findterm(end_of_file) :- !. 
  findterm(Term) :- 
        read(Term1), 
        Term = Term1, 
        write(Term1), nl, ! 
        ; 
        findterm(Term).
```

Can anyone help me with the second?

Comment: Would you outline what problem you are having with the second exercise?

Comment: You really need to write a better title to your question, for example, "Find a term in a file". The title as it stands at the moment gives no useful information as to what your problem is and what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following program?

```
findallterm(Term, File_name) :-
    open(File_name, read, Stream),  
    findterm(Stream, Term),
    close(Stream).

findterm(Stream, _) :-
    at_end_of_stream(Stream),
    !.  
findterm(Stream, Term) :-
    read(Stream, Term_data),       
    (  Term == Term_data
    -> write( Term_data ), nl
    ;  true
    ),      
    findterm(Stream, Term).
```

Input file is the following.
'c:/work/data.txt'

```
sun.
mercury.
sun.
mercury.
venus.
earth.
sun.
mercury.
venus.
```

Result

```
6 ?- findallterm( mercury, 'C:/work/data.txt' ).
mercury
mercury
mercury

7 ?- findallterm( venus, 'C:/work/data.txt' ).
venus
venus
```

Comment: Edinburgh style IO is deprecated. **Use ISO Prolog IO** instead!

Comment: I changed the program with ISO Prolog IO.

Comment: Better now! Thank you.